# C# Optimization and dotnet CLI vs csc

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am trying to squeeze every bit of performance out of my compile C# project. I am using "dotnet" CLI with .Net Core 2.2. My question is: is there an equivalent to the csc.exe "-optimize" option in "dotnet"? Would csc with optimize option produce faster code?

Comment: `dotnet build -c Release`

Comment: You probably want to focus on profiling your code, and concentrating on the areas which the profiler highlights (e.g. making algorithms more efficient, reducing allocations in those areas, etc)

Comment: Thanks kevinGosse and canton7. The dotnet build -c Release did the trick. And yes, the next step is using the profiler to make the code more efficient. For the time being, I am comparing the current version of the code to an older Fortran version while the code base are very similar.